# Matplotlib: How to plot labelled line graphs of dictionary pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a dictionary of time series data in the following structure:

```
# {"second": [size, label]}
dict = {0.6: [100, 0],
        1.1: [120, 1],
        1.8: [220, 2]}
```

The dictionary above keeps track of the size and label **until** the corresponding second. Considering the example above, I'd like to plot lines in the same graph:

- green line for the label 0 between seconds: ( 0, 0.6 **]**
  (0.6 included)
- blue line for the label 1 between seconds: **(** 0.6, 1.1 **]**
  (0.6 excluded, 1.1 included)
- red line for the label 2 between seconds: **(** 1.1, 1.8 ]

  (1.1 excluded, 1.8 included)

I have many data points in a dictionary for approximately 10 minutes of data. I am planning to split the x-axis e.g. for every 10 seconds, so the data above will be shown as tiny spikes in the whole graph. I cannot use scattering for this case, there should be one line graph across the time [0 to n) (composed of different graphs with different labels(colors) as in the points above).

Is this achievable by using matplotlib, or do I need to find another way?
Thanks!

Comment: what are your expected y-values? for these x-ranges?

Comment: In the example,

y = 100 between the seconds ( 0 , 0.6 ]    (0.6 included)

y = 120 between the seconds ( 0.6, 1.1 ]  (0.6 excluded, 1.1 included)

y = 220 between the seconds ( 1.1, 1.8 ]  (1.1 excluded, 1.8 included)

Comment: @JohanC I still have a dictionary of labels, to fetch the relevant label name based on the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.plot` by default draws lines between the given positions. As only one point is given at each call, no lines are drawn.  `plt.scatter` can draw one (or more) points with a given color.

You can first collect all the x and all the y values into lists, and then draw a line plot(`plt.plot`). If you want a step function, you can use `plt.step` instead. On top of those lines you can plot colored dots (`plt.scatter`). Or you could draw short lines via `plt.plot([x_0, x_1], [y, y])`.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

dict = {0.22: [100, 0],
        0.68: [180, 1],
        1.12: [210, 2]}
legendMap = {0: ["blue", "A"],
             1: ["red", "B"],
             2: ["green", "C"]}
x = list(dict.keys())
x.sort()  # needed in case the values wouldn't be ordered
y = [dict[xi][0] for xi in x]
# leave out the following line if you don't need the vertical lines
plt.step([0] + x, [y[0]] + y, color='black', ls=':', lw=0.5, where='pre')
used_legend_ids = set()
for xi0, xi1, yi in zip([0] + x[:-1], x, y):
    legend_id = dict[xi1][1]
    color, label = legendMap[legend_id]
    if legend_id in used_legend_ids:
        label = None
    else:
        used_legend_ids.add(legend_id)
    plt.plot([xi0, xi1], [yi] * 2, color=color, label=label)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(25)) # set a tick every 25 units
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To draw bars instead of horizontal lines, you could replace

```py
plt.plot([xi0, xi1], [yi] * 2, color=color, label=label)
```

by

```py
plt.bar(xi0, yi, width=xi1-xi0, align='edge', color=color, label=label, alpha=0.4)
```

Or even have both the bars and the lines (in that case you should leave out one of the two `label=label` parameters, to avoid a double legend).

To draw the plot of the comments, you could iterate through `y` similar as through `x`:

```
for xi0, xi1, yi0, yi1 in zip([0] + x[:-1], x, [0] + y[:-1], y):
    legend_id = dict[xi1][1]
    color, label = legendMap[legend_id]
    if legend_id in used_legend_ids:
        label = None
    else:
        used_legend_ids.add(legend_id)
    plt.plot([xi0, xi1], [yi0, yi1], color=color, label=label)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! However, while dealing with my problem, I have realized that I misexplained my question. I have just edited the question, can you have a look at it, please? Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's so close! :) The difference is, y = 100 from the second 0 until the second 0.22, y = 180 from the second 0.22 to the second 0.68 and etc.

Comment: Yes, {"second": [size, label] } represents that the "size" is the size of a data of type "label"   until the "second" from beginning the one former second. In case of the first element (like 0.22 in the example), the former second is 0 obviously.

Comment: Thanks, Sir! I guess the "colors" list is redundant, while the first line under the for loop stands there. I implemented your way into my code, but there are several issues.

https://pasteboard.co/JMw7B038.png

The first one is the legend as you see. The other issue is that the data that gave this output is for 177 seconds. If we split x-axis for e.g. every 10 seconds, can we produce a signal-like graph? Also maybe scaling y-axis for e.g. every 200 kbit would make the graphs smoother.

Comment: This fixed the legend issue, makes sense, thanks. Scaling the y-axis was about making the splits larger, like 0-200-400 instead of 0-100-200-300-400. I tried to remove the vertical dotted-lines but removing "ls" from the step method did not work, I don't know why.

Comment: You can simply leave out the call to `plt.step(....)` if you don't need the vertical lines. You can use the `MultipleLocator` to set more or fewer ticks on an axis. I just added an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I have something like this: https://pasteboard.co/JMxJCm8.png

It doesn't seem that much readable, but the reason is the video that is being used to extract the frames is approx. 15 minutes. I am trying to review the size of each type of frame across time.

Comment: I added some possible code to draw bars instead of horizontal lines.

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know what to say, many thanks for all those great ideas! Now it looks like: https://pasteboard.co/JMz2tqQ.png

Comment: You can add `ax.margins(x=0.02)` to have less margins. (Set it to zero for no margins),

Comment: Adding plt.margins(x=0) gives me this: https://pasteboard.co/JMCrXeN.png

and I think it makes sense, considering the video length could grow.

Comment: Hello again @JohanC ! Please let me I ask you again something about this, I am stuck here :) Instead of bars or horizontal lines, how can I convert this graph to a line graph? I mean: this is the data I have https://pasteboard.co/JOC6gcg.png , and I'd like to draw this in this way, based on the gamestages https://pasteboard.co/JOCi7Yh.jpg
I mean, in the second 1.171, the value is 446 and until here, label is 0. In the second 1.371, the value is 175 and between the seconds [1.171, 1.371] the label is 1 and so on. (I highlighted the values on the graph to clarify, its not necessary normally)

Comment: In your code above, shouldn't we change only the [yi] * 2 part in this line:
plt.plot([xi0, xi1], [yi] * 2, color=color, label=label)
Because [yi, yi] gives us horizontal line, we need to change this to the [former_yi, yi] ? And of course, for loop should be changed accordingly.

Comment: I updated the code with an example of iterating through y similar as through x.

Comment: Thanks! Just before your edit, I made it in this way by using your suggestion
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bX5s6hCsz2/
It gives the same result with your edit. Thanks a lot!